# Group by with having clause a key not equal

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

I have a table structure and values as:-

```
used_items

id  item_name   qty

24  Potatoes    0
25  Potatoes    500
26  test        88
27  Wheat       3
28  abc         10
```

I want to group according to `item_name` such as query should return single `item_name` where `qty!=0`.
I have used this query-

```
SELECT * from used_items group by item_name having qty!='0'
```

This query doesn't return Potatoes, the result-

```
  id    item_name   qty

    26  test        88
    27  Wheat       3
    28  abc         10
```

Expected Result-

```
id  item_name   qty

25  Potatoes    500
26  test        88
27  Wheat       3
28  abc         10
```

It should also return the item_name `Potatoes` with non zero value including in the group.
How can I achieve this?

Edits-
I have used `Group by` because i want unique `item_name` and it should skip the `item_name` if `qty` is 0 for all same `item_name`. But the query skips if atleast one of the row `qty` is 0(such as `Potatoes`).
Also, if qty is 0, it should get the row which matches the `item_name` according to the id ascending. Hope i am clear, for eg;

The data:-

```
id  item_name   qty

24  Potatoes    0
25  Potatoes    500
27  Potatoes    400
28  test        88
29  Wheat       3
30  abc         10
```

Expected result, returning unique `item_name` with first inserted non-zero value

```
id  item_name   qty
25  Potatoes    500
28  test        88
29  Wheat       3
30  abc         10
```

Comment: If there are 2 rows for abc with quantities 10 and 20, what is your expected result for abc?

Comment: @forpas it should return according to the first inserted id, if abc with qty=10 is inserted first and qty!=0, should return abc with qty=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want for each `item_name` the 1st non `0` (for the quantity) row then you can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tablename WHERE item_name = t.item_name AND qty <> 0)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5aef9c8404e8abc7d0d3ea7e0d43df4d).
Results:

```
> id | item_name | qty
> -: | :-------- | --:
> 25 | Potatoes  | 500
> 28 | test      |  88
> 29 | Wheat     |   3
> 30 | abc       |  10
```

Comment: It did work and i got the expected result, Thanks @forpas

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your query is the problem. When you `GROUP BY` by you are working with aggregating data and the `HAVING` clause functions on an aggregate. Your query doesn't do any aggregation at the moment.

So you'd need to aggregate the `qty` by `SUM` or `AVG` or `MAX` in order to have an effective group by. I also wouldn't think about excluding the `id` here, because it's not useful in the aggregate.

For example:

```
SELECT item_name, MIN(qty)
FROM used_items
GROUP BY item_name
HAVING MIN(qty) <> '0'
```

You can also consider using `DISTINCT` if you just want to find unique combinations. Again, the `id` won't be useful with `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` does not aggregate.

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_name, qty
FROM used_items
WHERE qty <> '0';
```

Having a second look, if all you want to do is exclude all 0 `qty` rows, all you need is:

```
SELECT id, item_name, qty
WHERE qty <> '0';
```

Finally, just check that the data type of `qty` is actually a `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` like type. It really would make a lot more sense if it was an `INT`.

---

EDIT:
You can use a `WHERE` clause with a `GROUP BY` to exclude `qty` values that are `0`. And since `qty` is an `INT` data type, you don't need to put values in quotes `'`.

Example:

```
SELECT item_name, MAX(qty)
FROM used_items
WHERE qty <> 0
GROUP BY item_name
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited my question, the first query does the same it doesn't return the item_name with 0 even if there exists same item_name with non-zero qty, and yes the qty is of type INT @Jason

Comment: Hi @pse, I see why you want to use `group by`. So, you can also exclude the `qty`'s that are `0` by using a `where` clause before the `group by`. I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the group by without an aggregate function? If I understood your question, to achieve your expected result you can just..

```
SELECT DISTINCT(item_name), qty from used_items where qty!='0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id) id, item_name, SUM(qty) qty
  FROM used_items
 GROUP BY item_name
HAVING SUM(qty) > 0
 ORDER BY MAX(id);
```

should do it for you.  See this. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9hmTPkNkhpjqGrFvUeLzjW/1

`MAX(id)`'s purpose is to get a valid `id` column value even from your `GROUP BY` operation.

You were misusing MySQL's [notorious non-standard GROUP BY handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and therefore getting strange results.